Getting INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR even though my Springboot project is connected to MongoDB even thought the status responce is 200 OK
I am using Postman to test out the API, the server port is 3001
enter image description here
for example
//  @RequestMapping(value = "/getSongById/{songId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @GetMapping(value = "/getSongById/{songId}")
  public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getSongById(@PathVariable("songId") String songId,
      HttpServletRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    response.put("path", String.format("GET %s", Utils.getUrl(request)));

    DbQueryStatus dbQueryStatus = songDal.findSongById(songId);

    response.put("message", dbQueryStatus.getMessage());
    response = Utils.setResponseStatus(response, dbQueryStatus.getdbQueryExecResult(), dbQueryStatus.getData());

    return response;
  }

i was trying out this part on postman but got this
{
    "path": "POST http://localhost:3001/addSong",
    "message": "POST",
    "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
}

but for some reason I'm getting this error
